# MS Word: Center align only image in a list

Tags: microsoft-word

I have made a numbered list in Word 2010. Each list entry has an image as well. I want to center align all images, but when I try to center align an image, the text above get centered as well.

> [image: MS Word 2010 - List with images]

How can I center align images in the list without centering the text above and below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here's what you do:

1. Right click on the image and select, 'Size & Position...'
2. Select the 'Text Wrapping' tab
3. Select 'Top & Bottom'
4. Select the 'Position' tab
5. Under the 'Horizontal' section, select 'Alignment' and then select 'Centered' relative to 'Column'

Unfortunately, doing this for multiple images is problematic. Format painter won't work. Also, simply using the Macro Recorder causes problems when trying to select the image.

So, creating a VBA macro and binding it to a key would seem to be the only way forward to make this super-efficient. Here are two helpful posts in this regard:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/j4ZaBiOYKDU
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809475/insert-resize-and-relocate-image-using-a-microsoft-word-macro

From the first of these references, I have tested the following VBA macro. Seems to work fine!

```
Sub FormatMyPicture()  
   Dim myShape As Shape

   If Selection.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
       Set myShape = Selection.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
   ElseIf Selection.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
       Set myShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   Else
       MsgBox "Please select a picture first."
       Exit Sub
   End If

   With myShape
       .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
       .WrapFormat.DistanceTop = InchesToPoints(0.2)
       .WrapFormat.DistanceBottom = InchesToPoints(0.2)
       .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
       .Left = wdShapeCenter
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: On more thing, how do I do the same with all other images easily? Format painter is not working here :(

Comment: Yes, I was just trying that and found that format painter doesn't work. I also tried selecting multiple images but struggled with that. Lastly, tried defining a style but it seems that is problematic. This suspect this is all because the property is being set for the image and not the paragraph. Creating a macro and binding a key to it would probably be the most efficient. If I think of something else, I'll let you know.

Comment: I just tried recording a macro, can't even do that. While recording macro I am not allowed to select an image, so no way to change its properties.

Comment: A bit quicker way. Select an Image then  press `Alt,J,P,T,W,O,Alt,J,P,A,A,C` :-|

Comment: Added details on creating a macro

Comment: This is a bit easier in modern versions as, once you select the image, you can use the tab `Picture Format` then the buttons `Wrap Text` and `Align`.

Comment: Inserting multiple images one after another would make them overlap. Suggesting Step 6 - while on the "Position" tab, uncheck "Allow overlap"

Answer (score 0):

To align center all inline image in MS Word:

**Step 1**: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA Editor

**Step 2**: Go to **`Insert`** then **`Module`**

**Step 3**: In the VBA Editor type following code snippet

```
Sub centerPictures()
  Dim shpIn As InlineShape, shp As Shape
  For Each shpIn In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    shpIn.Select
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  Next shpIn
  For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    shp.Select
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  Next shp
End Sub
```

Step 4: Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or press **`Run Sub`** to apply this change

Answer (score 0):

Hope this wil help someone special

```
Sub rezize_center_newline()

Dim i As Long
Dim shpIn As InlineShape, shp As Shape

With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .Height = InchesToPoints(4)
            .Width = InchesToPoints(5.32)
            .Range.InsertAfter Chr(13)
        End With
    Next i
    For Each shpIn In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        shpIn.Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Next shpIn
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        shp.Select
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Next shp
End With
End Sub
```